# How to convert postgres time format ( timestamp without timezone) to Date object(Sun Dec 01 2019 17:55:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) in React?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql

I need to save the timestamp I am getting from database as date object in react. Postgres format of date: timestamp without timezone. 
Required format:  Sun Dec 01 2019 17:55:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: Please review [ask] in the help section. Following that as a template for your question greatly increases your chance of getting a satisfactory answer.  Your request has 2 issues: First it's self contradictory. You say you need "timestamp without timezone" but your required format is "timestamp with timezone".  Second, you are misunderstanding date format. Format is strictly for 'viewing' purposes. All Postgres date types (date, timestamp with or without timezone) are **_Always Stored_** the same. Lastly, I do not find India Standard Time in the table pg_timezone_name you might want to check.

Comment: @Belayer Okay, i got it. What I was trying to say is : I get this timestamp from backend: "2019-12-02T03:00:00Z", which I need as a date object in frontend(using react). All I had to do is use moment library, convert to date object using toDate(). :